# How do I load the Demo temperature program on an MSP 430 access point and end point?

Tags: msp430

I have successfully downloaded Code Composer Studio v5 on linux under evaluation license and I also have two devices: .

- [MSP430 2.4-GHz Wireless Target Board](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-rf2500t) (end point)
- [MSP430 Wireless Development Tool](http://www.ti.com/tool/ez430-rf2500) (access point)

My understanding is there is a temperature sensor on one of the devices and it wirelessley sends a signal to the other device indicating the temperature.

My question is: how do I download, install, compile, and execute this temperature demo on Code Composer Studio v5?

I would appreciate all / any guidance regarding this.  A tutorial that has step by step instructions would be perfect.

CCS is complaning that "TIMSP430-USB.xml" does not exist.  What should I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configurations XML_version="1.2" id="configurations_0">
<configuration XML_version="1.2" id="configuration_0">
    <instance XML_version="1.2" desc="TI MSP430 USB1" href="connections\TIMSP430-USB.xml" id="TI MSP430 USB1" xml="TIMSP430-USB.xml" xmlpath="connections"/>
    <connection XML_version="1.2" id="TI MSP430 USB1">
        <instance XML_version="1.2" href="drivers\msp430_emu.xml" id="drivers" xml="msp430_emu.xml" xmlpath="drivers"/>
        <platform XML_version="1.2" id="platform_0">
            <instance XML_version="1.2" desc="MSP430F2274" href="devices\MSP430F2274.xml" id="MSP430F2274" xml="MSP430F2274.xml" xmlpath="devices"/>
        </platform>
    </connection>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have the source code for "eZ430-RF2500 Wireless Sensor Monitor" in a zip file but I'm not even sure how to import this into Code Composer Studio.  Is there a way to load demo code via the IDE over the internet? Right now my goal is to load the temperature demo on both devices and get it to execute successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not necessarily going to be successful doing this because the linux CCS 5.3.0 version is documented to not support the ez430 type of "FET" programming device which is also used in the EZ430 which programs the RF2500T board.  The "Linux Host Support" page on the processors.wiki.ti.com site says that, and I think the CCS5 release notes do also.
If you had the FET430UIF programmer and a suitable cable adapter you could program the board with that since the FET430UIF is supported under LINUX at this time.  I don't belive the MSP430 LAUNCHPAD's built in FET is supported at this time so you can probably not use the spy by wire output from that to do the programming.  It will work as advertised under CCS for MS Windows.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Linux_Host_Support

Comment: Looks like you're right.  I switched over to Windows and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is more an extended comment than an answer...

Well the first step is to download the code, extract it somewhere and in CCS use option Project->Import existing CCS Eclipse Project.

Then browse to the directory where you extracted the project. Go to subdirectory eZ430-RF2500 Wireless Sensor Monitor\Embedded\CCS\eZ430-RF2500_WSM and select it.

CCS should detect project now. Check the automatically import referenced projects box. After that, you should be able to build the project. Connect the board to the computer and click debug. If everything is connected correctly, CCS should load the code onto the board.

You should also take time to read the readme files in the project directory and the comments in the code.

I don't have that board, so I can't check if that's all that should be done. It may be worth taking time to resolve the warnings that appear after building.

Comment: Hi AndrejaKo - I'm really close.  I was able to successfully open the project and I get 1 error: 
File connections\TIMSP430-USB.xml does not exist.  Was included by file /root/AVL/eZ430-RF2500 Wireless Sensor Monitor/Embedded/CCS/eZ430-RF2500_WSM/MSP430F2274.ccxml MSP430F2274.ccxml /eZ430-RF2500_WSM line 0 So it appears like the file "MSP430F2274.ccxml" is referencing an XML file that does not exist.

Comment: AndrejKo - I updated my question above with the offending XML file: MSP430F2274.ccxml above.